# Problem with get web element value in for loop with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have weird problem with Selenium 4.18.1 and Python 3.12.2 I don't understand.
I'd like to get particular values from web element by looping all elements as in code below:

```
loads = waste_collection_points_editing_page.get_loads()

actual_loads_values = []
    for i in loads:
        # time.sleep(1)
        values = i.text.split("\n")
        del values[2:]
        actual_loads_values.append(values)
```

But when I do it I don't get this values. I get only empty lists.

I try do the same in debug mode - what's interesting list of web elements are initialized and when I try get this values in this debug mode in pyhon console I can get this values with no problem.
I try add this line
`time.sleep(1)`
and it works with it, but I don't exactly understand why.

Can someone explain me why I can't get this values without time.sleep. Is there a problem with Selenium speed or something else? I'm new in automation with Selenium and I try figure it out.

Comment: your code run faster than website load. Selenium uses "waiters" something like wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(........"

Comment: Thank You, Wonka, that simple answer but now I have aha moment.

Answer (score 0):

It is basicly it takes time while page loading. You can use
**WebDriverWait** and **Expected Conditions**. WebDriverWait is best options, I had same problems and it helped me lot.

You can take a look into this.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html